# Opening a contact file sent from outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

Im trying to open contact files sent with outlook (I believe).

Problem is that they have no extension, only clue I have is that `IPM.Contact` is mentioned in the file...

Anyone know how to open them?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, if they have no extension is to rename them and manually add the `IPM` extension

That being said, I thought `VCF` is the normal extension, so if the above doesn't work, I would rename it with `.VCF`

Lastly, if the above two do not work, download the file and put it somewhere safe then go in to your address book and look for the import option and simply select that file.

Please leave feedback and tell me what way worked and/or if you need more help.

Comment: No success, ipm had nothing to open with and opening as a vcf contained no info. outlook can only import vcard and ical :(

Comment: @sam, sorry I couldn't be more help - perhaps you can email your contact and ask them what program it was created in, or if you want to forward the email/file to me (email in my profile) I will be happy to look at it for you.